# How can you persist a logged-in user with firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Thanks a bunch for reading this newbie's question.

So, there is a ReactJS app which is using firebase for its authentication.

Everytime the page is refreshed, the user is gone forever until you login in with the redirected login page.

What have been done so far?

Well, after plodding through all the possible Stackoverflows flowing flawless answers, following have been done:

1. Implemented the onAuthStateChanged() function like as it appears below:

```js
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('user is logged in');
            } else {
                console.log('user is logged out now')
            }
        });
```

2. Set the persistence, which seems to be a silent worker, as follows:

```js
 firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
        .then(function () {
          console.log("successfully set the persistence");
    
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("failed to ser persistence: " + error.message)
        });
```

Every page reloads logs the user out just like that.
Gone!.
Nothing. Not even a trace of its dust!

To have a better understanding of this crippling code, I can give you the following screenshots of the console messages.

You get this when you logged in

[image]

And the following when the page is refreshed.

Why do you think this error pops up even after applying the above?

Thanks again!

Update1: Took down the setPersistence thing. And it turns out that the user is logged in even after page reloads to the login.

Update 2: User is actually get pulled out when refreshing the page. Now that's what we need to solve here. What do you guys think?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Auth SDK enables persistence by default.  If you want that default behavior, don't call `firebase.auth().setPersistence()` at all.  Just use `onAuthStateChanged` to know when the persisted user object is first available.

Comment: Hey Doug!, Thank you for your answer. I will try that and see how it goes

Comment: So, I take down that line. Still the aforementioned error prevails. Now on refresh  only the  "user is Logged in" message shown.

Comment: What error?  You're showing no errors here.

Comment: Mistake. Not an error. Just that nothing got better by doing the above.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what the problem is.  The auth state observer seems to be working just fine and telling you about the previously signed in user.

Comment: Is the question unclear? The problem is that on every page refresh the app is redirected to the login page, which I thought due to the logging out. It seems like something else

Comment: What exactly happens is that when you refresh the page, the app redirects you to the place where you previously logged in. And you have to login again to access the app. So, is the user logging out on refresh or what?

Comment: There's not enough code here to know what that problem is.  All I can tell you is that the console log that shows the user is signed in is all the proof that the user is being persisted.  Do what you need to do in that bit of code to make sure the user is navigated to the right thing after you see that they're signed in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225576/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Hey, if the user is persisted why does the app automatically redirected and ask us to login back in order to user it?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately along with the relevant code that doesn't work the way you expect.  There should be enough information in that question that anyone can duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Here's the link for the newly created one ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176716/why-does-the-user-getting-redirected-to-the-login-page-on-refresh